# iphone app submission process

Tags: iphone, itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I am done with my first iphone app (SO helps a lot..thanks). Now i want to submit my app to app store for review. I can use itunes connect to submit my app. I have few questions.

1) I dont know how to create a build for release. What i mean is i dont know what profile it requires. There are help videos but they all guide to do development provisioning not for release.

2) Where do i specify all app attributes like Genre and so on.

3) I dont have iTunesArtwork but it does not show in my itunes when i create distribute build. Is it going to same for release.

Hope my question is genuine.

Comment: Please make an effort to use capitalization and punctuation. If you really appreciate help on SO, try to give a little back to the community by making it easier to read your questions.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Trying my best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The iTunes Connect has a guide.  Goto the iTunes connect portal and there is a PDF guide you can download listed at the bottom of the page.  Follow the step by step instructions listed there.
2. Genre etc is specified during the submission process in iTunes Connect.
3. The artwork is also set in the iTunes Connect portal.  However if you want to see it on development builds you can add the 512x512 png to the root of your project and name it "iTunesArtwork" (no extension).

Hope that is helpful.  Really everything you need is in the developer guide found at [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com).

Answer (score -1):

1 Link: [the Apple guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/distribution/index.action).

2 & 3 please follow BigJason's answer.