# How to include 512X512 icon in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, bundle

Apple HIG says I must include a 512x512 and a 29x29 icons along with the 57x57 icon. Now how do I "include" the large icons? I have Icon.png and Icon-Small.png files, but how do I include the 512x512 version of the icon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will be able to upload the 512x512 image separatley, when you submit your app for inclusion in the app store - it does not need to be part of your application bundle.

More info in the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725414/iphone-app-submission-process).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, submitted my first app..fingers crossed!